# Where can I download PEVerify.exe tool?

Tags: c#, .net, peverify

I ran into an InvalidProgramException. This article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312544/en-us

Suggests I run PEVerify.exe, but I can't seem to find it. Do you know where I can get it from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you installed Visual Studio. Just open a Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt (Startmenu - Programs - Visual Studio - Visual Studio Tools - Command Prompt) and enter PEVerify.exe

The path on your PC should be: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\PEVerify.exe`

Answer (score 5):

(Answer for 2021)

`PEVerify.exe` does not currently support .NET Core assemblies - only .NET Framework (1.0 through 4.8) assemblies. Microsoft has hinted that they'll add support back *eventually* but don't hold your breath. (I'm unsure about .NET Standard assemblies, though I assume they'll work as they can be loaded by .NET Framework programs fine).

The `PEVerify.exe` tool is no-longer part of the .NET SDK either, but it is now part of the Windows SDK or a typical Visual Studio 2019 installation, including for Windows 10, so you can find it in these locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\PEVerify.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\PEVerify.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\PEVerify.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\PEVerify.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\PEVerify.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\x64\PEVerify.exe

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the .NET Framework SDK.

[SDK for 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9B3A2CA6-3647-4070-9F41-A333C6B9181D&displaylang=en) (x86)

[SDK for 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en) (x86)

[SDK for 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FF6467E6-5BBA-4BF5-B562-9199BE864D29&displaylang=en) (ISO)

[SDK for 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) (ISO)

Answer (score 0):

[PEVerify.exe Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd(VS.80).aspx) is part of the [.NET Framework Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92(VS.71).aspx). You can download the 2.0 SDK here (354 MB): http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec

Edit1: Or like Oliver said - go to your Visual Studio command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin